# Set InputBinding(KeyboardBinding) in ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, key-bindings, inputbinding

I wish to set the Inputbinding of a listViewitem ... It should be a Keyborad binding and not a mouse binding...

I want to Execute a function in my view model when the User selectes an item and presses `Enter` Key

## Style for ListViewItem

```
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type CustomView:PlainView},
                                    ResourceId=ImageViewItem}"           
       TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">

    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,2,5,2" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid Margin="2,0,2,0">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientOver"
                                   Fill="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Stroke="{DynamicResource MouseOverBorderBrush}" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientSelectedDisabled"
                                   Fill="{DynamicResource ListItemSelectedBrush}"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Stroke="{DynamicResource ListItemSelectedBorderBrush}" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientSelected"
                                   Fill="{DynamicResource PressedBrush}"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Stroke="{DynamicResource PressedBorderBrush}"
                                   StrokeThickness="1" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource OutsideFontColor}" />
</Style>
```

## My DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="centralTile">
    
    <StackPanel Width="80"
                Height="40"
                KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="True">
        <StackPanel.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.KeyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></KeyBinding>
        </StackPanel.InputBindings>
        <Grid>              
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.KeyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </Button>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Water lilies.jpg" />
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="13"
                   Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I Cant Seem to find a way to do it...

I attached my InputBinding in DataTemplate as well has in Style Nothing Works

```
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.KeyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></KeyBinding>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any .Net version prior to 4.0? If so the binding on `KeyBinding.Command` and `KeyBinding.CommandParameter` wont work. You will have to use `CommandReference` API for that.

Otherwise if you are using .Net 4.0, then

1. Add a `KeyBinding` to `ListView`'s `InputBindings`.
2. You will have to bind `KeyBinding.CommandParameter` to the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView`.

This way the command executes on `Enter` key press for the parameter which will be the selected item of the ListView (which is what I think you want to achieve)

Comment: I am using .Net 4.0 Client profile.... i even tried to use Net 4.0 the KeyBinding.Command works if i press a `Tab` after selecting a ListViewitem.

Comment: but What in the Case where i have to set inputbinding for `ListView` & 'ListViewItem' using the same key to perform diffetent functions for `ListView` & `ListViewItem`....